# Missing the index.cshtml view in an MSBuild + TeamCity build

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, msbuild, razor, teamcity

I have the strangest problem.  We have Razor views coming into our MVC3 project.  Everything is fantastic until TeamCity and MSBuild run to gather an artifact.  All razor views **except** for Index.cshtml will be placed in the artifact zip. The view file is clearly in the buildAgent work directory and was successfully retrieved from github but it simply is ignored when the artifact is gathered but razor views in the same folder are OK?

We have already removed the entire file from source control and readded but no fix.

Anyone encounter a similar problem or have a hint of what to check?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is the artifact pattern you've used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked build action property for the view? Make sure it is set to Content.

Comment: you were exactly correct!  thank you so much.  I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: where is that property?